# Adding multiple rows to database using WHILE loop

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, while-loop

I have a system that inserts student marks into the database. When a user enters the marks, he/she enters the marks for many students (minimum 30), (in a form format) so the form has the student name label and an input field for entering the mark.

My challenge is that when only one student is entered into the database. The rest do not get inserted

How can I when I press the add button, have all the students I've entered marks for, be inserted into the database.

Below is my code.
The HTML /Form code

```
while($row = $marks_query->fetch_assoc()) {

$student_id=$row["student_id"];
$student_name=$row['student_lastname'].' '.$row['student_midname'].' '.$row['student_firstname'];

echo '<tr>

<td class="align-middle">' . $student_name.'</td>';
?>  
    <td class="align-middle"><input type="number" class="form-control marks" placeholder="Enter Marks" name="marks" ></td>


<?php
echo '</tr>';
}

?>
<input type="hidden" name="class_list" id="class_list" value="<?php echo $class_list;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="subject_list" id="subject_list" value="<?php echo $subject_list;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="teacher_id" id="teacher_id" value="<?php echo $teacher_id;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="assessment" id="assessment" value="<?php echo $assessment;  ?>" >
<input type="hidden" name="student_id" id="student_id" value="<?php echo $student_id;  ?>" >

</tbody>

</table>

<button  class="btn btn-outline-primary col-md-auto float-right" name="add_marks" id="add_marks"  onclick="addMarks();">Add Student Marks</button>

<script type="text/javascript">


<script type="text/javascript">


    function addMarks(){
var class_list = "<?php echo $class_list; ?>";
var student_id = "<?php echo $student_id; ?>";
var subject_list = "<?php echo $subject_list; ?>";
var teacher_id = "<?php echo $teacher_id; ?>";
var assessment = "<?php echo $assessment; ?>";
var marks=$("#marks").val();


        $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"insert_marks.php",
     data: { class_list: class_list, subject_list: subject_list, student_id: student_id,teacher_id:teacher_id,assessment:assessment,marks:marks },
        success:function(data){






        }
    });
}


</script>
```

Here is the PHP CODE
I'm still going to sanitize and the code and use Prepared statements to prevent SQL Injection

```
$assessment=$_POST['assessment'];
$class_list=$_POST['class_list'];
$subject_list=$_POST['subject_list'];
$marks=$_POST['marks'];
$teacher_id=$_POST['teacher_id'];
$student_id=$_POST['student_id'];



$insert_sql=mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO `aza_assesmentxmarks`(`id`, `student_id`, `teacher_id`, `assessement_id`, `subject_id`, `class_id`, `mark`, `date`) VALUES (NULL,'$student_id','$teacher_id','$assessment','$subject_list','$class_list','$marks',NOW())") or die(mysqli_error());

echo $marks;
?>
```

Comment: You have `<?php` in every file, and you have connected to the db, right?

Comment: The next thing you should do put the `mysqli_query()` inside of a loop.

Comment: What is the type for all of the data you're sending, is it a string, an array, etc.

Comment: the type of data I am sending is a string

Comment: How many times is the `addMarks()` function executed?

Comment: once, after all the marks have been added

Comment: So `addMarks()` is supposed to add all of the marks?

Comment: yes, Sir, it is supposed to add all of the marks

Comment: You have an error. [`mysqli_error()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) needs one argument. Please consider switching error mode on instead. [How to get the error message in MySQLi?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/1839439)

Comment: @Dharman Once I'm done with the first draft of code, I will then rebuild THE entire project using PDO

Comment: @Dharman, It doesn't show any error on my side Sir

Answer (score 0):

If you send all of the data as strings it's going to only create 1 record in the db. You should send all of the data as arrays and then iterate through the arrays with a `for` loop and then send the data from the arrays to the db on each cycle of the `for` loop. If you need any help, ask here.

Comment: Could you please provide the output or expected output of this code: `var class_list = "<?php echo $class_list; ?>";
var student_id = "<?php echo $student_id; ?>";
var subject_list = "<?php echo $subject_list; ?>";
var teacher_id = "<?php echo $teacher_id; ?>";
var assessment = "<?php echo $assessment; ?>";
var marks=$("#marks").val();`.

Comment: e.g Class_list=1, student_id=STUD_234, subject_list=2, teacher_id=TEACHER_45, assessment=2, marks=67

Comment: Is there only 1 string per student (e.g `var student_id="STUD_234"` ), or are there more (e.g `var student_id="STUD_234, STUD_235"`)?

Comment: The are more Sir.

Comment: what's the delimiter between the strings?